# How to use javascript find same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a little value

```
<div id='g' date='2014/9/11'> 2014/9/11A: 12:00 ~ 13:00 </div>
<div id='g' date='2014/9/12'> 2014/9/12B: 14:00 ~ 15:00 </div>
<div id='g' date='2014/9/12'> 2014/9/12B: 14:00 ~ 15:00 </div>
<div id='g' date='2014/9/12'> 2014/9/12A: 12:00 ~ 13:00 </div>
<div id='g' date='2014/9/13'> 2014/9/13C: 15:00 ~ 16:00 </div>
<div id='g' date='2014/9/25'> 2014/9/25A: 12:00 ~ 13:00 </div>
```

I want take a value, Examples : data = 2014/9/12

My code :

`var h = $("#g").attr("date");
if( h = "2014/9/12"){
    alert(h);
}`

but unlike the following

```
2014/9/12B: 14:00 ~ 15:00
2014/9/12B: 14:00 ~ 15:00
2014/9/12A: 12:00 ~ 13:00
```

everybody ,How can I do it?

Examples Code :[enter link JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucvafeLx/)

Comment: IDs ***MUST*** be unique. Use a class if you are going to have multiple elements.

Comment: it is very unclear what you are expecting

Comment: Thanks Dom ~ I think i know how can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if( h = "2014/9/25"){` is assignment. You need to use `==` to compare two values, not `=`.

Comment: Thank you are answer.
This I solved